# How do I create a child object before a parent object gets created? Can I bypass foreign key constraints?

Tags: android, sqlite, foreign-keys, parent-child

I have three tables: Term, Course, and Assessment. Term is the parent to Course, and Course is the parent to Assessment. When I am creating a course there is a listview of all existing terms. The user clicks on the term they want this course to be apart of, and a foreign key gets inserted that is equivalent to the id of the selected term. This works great without foreign key constraints. When I turn foreign key constraints on, I can't create a course if a term doesn't exist, or an assessment if a course doesn't exist. Obviously if the user creates a term first, then a course, then an assessment everything works but that is not practical. Can I not have foreign keys enabled while being able to create a child before a parent?

Here is where I create my tables

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TermDbSchema.TermTable.NAME + "(" +
                "_id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                TermDbSchema.TermTable.Cols.UUID + ", " +
                TermDbSchema.TermTable.Cols.TITLE + ", " +
                TermDbSchema.TermTable.Cols.START_DATE + ", " +
                TermDbSchema.TermTable.Cols.END_DATE +
                ")"
        );
        db.execSQL("create table " + TermDbSchema.CourseTable.NAME + "(" +
                "_id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                TermDbSchema.CourseTable.Cols.UUID + ", " +
                TermDbSchema.CourseTable.Cols.TITLE + ", " +
                TermDbSchema.CourseTable.Cols.START_DATE + ", " +
                TermDbSchema.CourseTable.Cols.END_DATE + ", " +
                TermDbSchema.CourseTable.Cols.CHOSEN_START_DATE + ", " +
                TermDbSchema.CourseTable.Cols.CHOSEN_END_DATE + ", " +

                TermDbSchema.CourseTable.Cols.COURSE_STATUS + ", " +
                TermDbSchema.CourseTable.Cols.OPTIONAL_NOTE + ", " +
                TermDbSchema.CourseTable.Cols.MENTOR_NAME + ", " +
                TermDbSchema.CourseTable.Cols.MENTOR_PHONE + ", " +
                TermDbSchema.CourseTable.Cols.MENTOR_EMAIL + ", " +
//this foreign key references TermTable
                TermDbSchema.CourseTable.Cols.COL_COURSE_TERM_REFERENCE + " INTEGER REFERENCES " + TermDbSchema.TermTable.NAME + "(_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE" + //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
                ")"
        );
        db.execSQL("create table " + TermDbSchema.AssessmentTable.NAME + "(" +
                "_id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                TermDbSchema.AssessmentTable.Cols.UUID + ", " +
                TermDbSchema.AssessmentTable.Cols.TITLE + ", " +
                TermDbSchema.AssessmentTable.Cols.ASSESS_TYPE + ", " +
                TermDbSchema.AssessmentTable.Cols.DUE_DATE + ", " +
                TermDbSchema.AssessmentTable.Cols.GOAL_DATE + ", " +
//this foreign key references CourseTable
                TermDbSchema.AssessmentTable.Cols.COL_ASSESS_COURSE_REFERENCE + " INTEGER REFERENCES " + TermDbSchema.CourseTable.NAME + "(_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE" + //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
                //"course_reference" + " INTEGER REFERENCES " + "courses" + "(_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE" +
                ")"
        );
    }
```

Here is my Tables schema:

```
public class TermDbSchema {
    public static final class TermTable {
        public static final String NAME = "terms";
        public static final class Cols {
            public static final String UUID = "uuid";
            public static final String TITLE = "title";
            public static final String START_DATE = "startdate";
            public static final String END_DATE = "enddate";

        }
    }
    public static final class CourseTable {
        public static final String NAME = "courses";
        public static final class Cols {
            public static final String UUID = "uuid";
            public static final String TITLE = "title";
            public static final String START_DATE = "startdate";
            public static final String END_DATE = "enddate";
            public static final String CHOSEN_START_DATE = "chosenstartdate";
            public static final String CHOSEN_END_DATE = "chosenenddate";

            public static final String COURSE_STATUS = "coursestatus";
            public static final String OPTIONAL_NOTE = "optionalnote";
            public static final String MENTOR_NAME = "mentorname";
            public static final String MENTOR_PHONE = "mentorphone";
            public static final String MENTOR_EMAIL = "mentoremail";
            public static final String COL_COURSE_TERM_REFERENCE = "term_reference";

        }
    }
    public static final class AssessmentTable {
        public static final String NAME = "assessments";
        public static final class Cols {
            public static final String UUID = "uuid";
            public static final String TITLE = "title";
            public static final String ASSESS_TYPE = "assesstype";

            public static final String DUE_DATE = "duedate";
            public static final String GOAL_DATE = "goaldate";
           public static final String COL_ASSESS_COURSE_REFERENCE = "course_reference";
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my code where I insert the values to the created Course object.

```
private static ContentValues getContentValues(Course course) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(CourseTable.Cols.UUID, course.getID().toString());
        values.put(CourseTable.Cols.TITLE, course.getTitle());
        values.put(CourseTable.Cols.START_DATE, course.getStartDate().getTime());
        values.put(CourseTable.Cols.END_DATE, course.getEndDate().getTime());
        values.put(CourseTable.Cols.CHOSEN_START_DATE, course.getChosenStartDate());
        values.put(CourseTable.Cols.CHOSEN_END_DATE, course.getChosenEndDate());

        values.put(CourseTable.Cols.COURSE_STATUS, course.getCourseStatus());
        values.put(CourseTable.Cols.OPTIONAL_NOTE, course.getCourseNote());
        values.put(CourseTable.Cols.MENTOR_NAME, course.getCourseMentorName());
        values.put(CourseTable.Cols.MENTOR_PHONE, course.getCourseMentorPhone());
        values.put(CourseTable.Cols.MENTOR_EMAIL, course.getCourseMentorEmail());
```

This inserts a foreign key that matches 
the primary key of the term the user wants 
this course to be apart of

```
        values.put(CourseTable.Cols.COL_COURSE_TERM_REFERENCE, course.getTermReference()); 
        return values;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can I bypass foreign key constraints?

Yes,

## 1. Simply don't add the ForeignKey constraint.

## 2. Use NULL

As long as NOT NULL is not specified then set the value to NULL.

e.g. consider :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS course;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS term;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS term (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, termname TEXT);
INSERT INTO TERM (termname) VALUES ('Term001'),('Term002');
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS course (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, coursename TEXT, term_ref INTEGER REFERENCES term(id));
INSERT INTO course (coursename, term_ref) VALUES ('Course001',1),('Course002',2),('Course003',null);
SELECT * FROM course;
```

which results in :-

[image]

***i.e. Course003 has no related/mapped entry in the term table** (in SQLite NULL is considered unique)*

## 3. DEFERRED

Probably impractical is to utilise `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED` **BUT** the constraint will be applied when committed and can only be used for an explicit transaction i.e. you'd have to add the term before committing the course (hence why it would likely be impractical)

## 4 Intermediate table

You could introduce a schema that allows items (such as courses) to be unrelated, and then related via a mapping table that maps a course to a term etc.

Where a course has to be associated with a term (such as for a potential attendee to book the course) enforce accessing the course via the mapping table (which could have Foreign Key definitions).